# How to use cout formatting statements to print the input and output in proper format?

Tags: c++, formatting

I have a 2d array which stores numbers for Maths and Chemistry for X number of sets. Below is how I take input for each class and store them in 2d array for each class.

```
Input for Maths class:
50 20 30 40 50

Input for Chemistry class:
90 70 20 10 40
```

- Now basis on above input for each class I need to calculate "BEST", "WORSE" and "AVERAGE" number.
- Also I need to calculate average for each set (out of 5) for both "Math" and "Chemistry" class and then come up with overall average here as well.

Once I take above input for Math and Chemistry class, I need to print like this in below format which will have data for point 1 and 2 above along with the input-

```
             1     2     3     4     5    
            *****************************
Math        50.00 20.00 30.00 40.00 50.00 
Chemistry   90.00 70.00 20.00 10.00 40.00
```

**Problem Statement**

I am able to do all above things and calculate point 1 and 2 easily but I am not able to figure out on how to print output in the above format which can show input and ouput in properly formatted way. As of now my program prints everything separately along with the output in different line after taking input -

```
int main()
{
    double val[2][5];
    //.. val array being populated


    return 0;
}
```

How can I use `cout.setf(ios::fixed)`, `cout.setf(ios::showpoint)` and `cout.precision(2)` and `cout.width(4);` in my above code to get the formatting I need?

Comment: Have a look at [{fmt}](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) for sane text processing.

Comment: I am learning basics so I am trying to understand on how to use `setf`, `precision` and `width` functions pretty much. Once I master this then I can try to look at other things.

Comment: First, fix your undefined behavior: `array[2][5]` and then you access `array[2][...]`. You can only access `array[0][...]` and `array[1][...]`

Comment: index starts from 0 right? @TedLyngmo hmmm I see

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Fixed. Not sure how it worked earlier. It's weird. Now I am using new array to store output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a way:

```
auto w = std::setw(6);   // for number like " 10.00" (6 chars)
auto wb = std::setw(8);  // for the numbers with more space between them
auto sw = std::setw(11); // for titles (math, chemistry)

// print the numbers above
cout << "         ";
for(int i=1; i<=5; ++i) std::cout << w << i;
std::cout << "     BEST    WORST  AVERAGE\n";

// print a line of *
std::cout << sw << "" << std::string(56,'*') << '\n';

cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed; // precision 2, fixed

cout << sw << std::left << "Math" << std::right;
for(auto ms : array[0]) std::cout << w << ms;
cout << wb << math_best << wb << math_worse << wb << math_average << '\n';

cout << sw << std::left << "Chemistry" << std::right;
for(auto cs : array[1]) std::cout << w << cs;
cout << wb << chemistry_best <<  wb << chemistry_worse << wb << chemistry_average << '\n';
```

Output

```
              1     2     3     4     5     BEST    WORST  AVERAGE
           ********************************************************
Math        50.00 20.00 30.00 40.00 50.00   50.00   20.00   38.00
Chemistry   90.00 70.00 20.00 10.00 40.00   90.00   10.00   46.00
```

Comment: Not to be that guy, but it's probably supposed to be worst* :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Let me understand this by reading in detail. Also how can I get `*****` and `1 2 3 4 5..` line on top of it? Just print as it is?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili :-) Probably. I didn't rename it. I would have to include the whole program then.

Comment: @AndyP `****...` you can get with `std::cout << std::string(count, '*');` - it will then print as many `*`'s as `count` says - or you can use filling. `1 2 3 4 5` is just a loop?

Comment: @AndyP I added a little more.